# How to re-generate dataset df at time t2 while having df at time t1 and cross-sectional dataset df' at time t1 and t2?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-analysis

I have a travel survey dataset df' collected in 2017 and also 2019. Note that individuals (households here) **are not necessarily identical** in 2017 and 2019 but **their features are**.

**Dataset df' in 2017:**

| household | income | size | delivery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100K | 2 | 2 |
| B | 150K | 4 | 0 |

**Dataset df' in 2019:**

| household | income | size | delivery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 75K | 1 | 1 |
| D | 100K | 4 | 5 |

Now I have another travel survey df (in 2017 only) that **has some features in common** with df':

**Dataset df in 2017:**

| household | rent/own | vehicle | delivery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | rent | Ford | 0 |
| F | own | GMC | 1 |

I am wondering how to use the **relationship** between samples of df' in 2017 and 2019 and also the **common features between df and df'** to regenerate the dataset df in 2019?

Is there any method or theoretical foundation that can assist us with doing so?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. It's not very clear to me what you're trying to do. Maybe you could add an example of the output that you would like to obtain? Also I don't understand what the delivery feature means.

Comment: @Erwan Basically, I want to use the temporal resolution of df' in 2017 and 2019 and project the data glued between (df'-17 and df - 17) through common features (monthly package delivery to the household, others...) on df- 19. Hypothetically, If we have the **relationship** between samples of (df'-17 and df'-19), and the **relationship** between df'-17 and df-17, is there a way to generate a new dataset df-19 given the relationships above?

Comment: In general it seems difficult and risky to me, unless there is some expert knowledge which can help and guarantee reliability to some extent. I don't see how the relationship between 2017 and 2019 would be usable, especially with a single year (2017) available. If you had multiple years you could do a real time series prediction: you could maybe use the existing 2019 data to check that the system predicts decently, then apply it to predict the missing information. So the only thing I can think of is training on 2017 and then predicting on 2019, but then the time dimension would be lost.

Comment: But I'm not particularly expert on this, there might be methods that I'm not aware of.